# :target not changing background-color if pre defined

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a reason why this code does not work but the following code does work.

Not working:

```
#contact {
border-radius: 10px;
max-width: 40%;
margin: 2% 4%;
float: left;
padding-left: 2%;
padding-bottom: 2%;  
color: black 
background-color: #CF8D56;
}

:target {
background-color: #E6E6E6;
color: black;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbWmbj

Working:

```
#contact {
border-radius: 10px;
max-width: 40%;
margin: 2% 4%;
float: left;
padding-left: 2%;
padding-bottom: 2%;
color: black  
background-color: #CF8D56;
}

#contact:target {
background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPwMNE

I do not understand why the fisrt example does not work, because if I was to do the same without pre-defining #contact background-color it works:

Working:

```
#contact {
border-radius: 10px;
max-width: 40%;
margin: 2% 4%;
float: left;
padding-left: 2%;
padding-bottom: 2%;  
color: black 
}

:target {
background-color: #E6E6E6;
color: black;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpKodM

Any reason for this?

Comment: Have a read of this article on CSS specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the CSS specificity priority. Defining a rule by an element's id has a higher priority than defining a rule by a pseudo-selector. For a full explanation on the priority, check [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

You could override the priority by adding the `important` keyword. In your first example, update your style rule to

```
:target {
  background-color: #E6E6E6 !important;  
}
```

And it should work.

As @BoltClock has correctly pointed out in their comment, it's generally a better approach to not overuse the `important` keyword and when possible to make your other CSS selector more specific, like you have done in your second Pen.

Short answer: you already had the correct solution :)

Comment: Or you could just go with the solution that was already shown to work in the question: using a more specific selector (as explained here).

Comment: @BoltClock of course, just pointing out that there are ways to override the default behaviour. Making your rules more specific in this case is definitely the better solution, I've added this to my answer.